# useState not updating state

Tags: reactjs, use-state

I have below code where I change state of `isDeleting`. This state is used to show the spinner on the delete button. Once the delete task is finished this state is changed to `false`

```
const { deleteExpense } = apiExpenses();
const [isDeleting, setIsDeleting] = useState(false)


const handleDeleteCompleted =  () => {
    setIsDeleting(true)
    
    const response = deleteExpense(fetchExpenseId);

    if(response) {
      setOpenConfirmDelete(false);
      setIsDeleting(false)
    }
};

\\in JSX

<ButtonError
onClick={handleDeleteCompleted}
size="large"
sx={{
  mx: 1,
  px: 3,
}}
variant="contained"
startIcon={
  isDeleting ? <CircularProgress size="1rem" /> : null
}
disabled={isDeleting}
>
{t("Delete")}
</ButtonError>
```

When `handleDeleteCompleted` function runs it does not change state of `isDeleting` and if I console it always stay in `false`. It runs `deleteExpense` function as well.

and for that reason, the spinner never popup.

What is getting wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should `deleteExpense()` be an `async` function? In your current example you're treating it as a synchronous function. This results in that there is no time between setting `setIsDeleting(true)` and `setIsDeleting(false)` because React bundles these actions when they happen synchronously, the latter overrides the former and you never actually invoke `setIsDeleting(true)`.

To fix this, try making your function `async`

```
const handleDeleteCompleted = async() => {
    setIsDeleting(true)
    
    const response = await deleteExpense(fetchExpenseId);

    if(response) {
      setOpenConfirmDelete(false);
      setIsDeleting(false)
    }
};
```